# Get response body from API Gateway call in Lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I know how to set up API Gateway and link it to a Lambda function. What I don't know, and God have I searched, is how to get the response body from API Gateway in Lambda.

How do I get it? I see it when I test the API in the AWS console.

Comment: Do you mean the get query parameters of the url and/or body parameters from the URL request to be accessed in the lambda function?

Comment: I'd like to know how to do both

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have to setup Body Mapping Template. Goto Gateway API -> API That you created -> Resources -> Method(Get/Post .. ) -> Integration Request -> Body Mapping Template -> Add Mapping Template 
`Content Type: application/json`

```js
{
  "body" : $input.json('$'),
  "headers": {
    #foreach($header in $input.params().header.keySet())
    "$header": "$util.escapeJavaScript($input.params().header.get($header))" #if($foreach.hasNext),#end

    #end
  },
  "method": "$context.httpMethod",
  "params": {
    #foreach($param in $input.params().path.keySet())
    "$param": "$util.escapeJavaScript($input.params().path.get($param))" #if($foreach.hasNext),#end

    #end
  },
  "query": {
    #foreach($queryParam in $input.params().querystring.keySet())
    "$queryParam": "$util.escapeJavaScript($input.params().querystring.get($queryParam))" #if($foreach.hasNext),#end
    #end
  }  
}
```

You should be able to access the variables in Lambda

`params.Item = event.query;` to access the query parameters

Check out these links for more information
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html

https://kennbrodhagen.net/2015/12/06/how-to-create-a-request-object-for-your-lambda-event-from-api-gateway/

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: That's right. I see the response body when I test it. However, if I call it from outside, I get the following: {"message":"Forbidden"}

Comment: You got it working?   Where do you see message: forbidden in the Lambda function or in the response in the browser?

Comment: I see it in the response in the browser

Comment: Nevermind, I got it to work. I had to deploy the API. Now, I can see the response. Woohooo!!! Thanks a lot.

Comment: Great!  Happy coding!